# Search Result Notification

Tags: python, django-models, wagtail

[image]

I am trying to make the code below me work. I added an if/else statement within the current if/else statement, but I don't believe I'm calling the right condition for the if/else statement to work.

*Search_Results.html*

```
{% if page.filter_term %}
<section>

   {% if results %}
    {# SEARCH RESULT SUCCESSFUL #}

    <div class="alert alert-success page-title-center">
        <h3 style="padding-top:1em;">Search Results For: <span>{{ page.filter_term }}</span></h3>
    </div>

   {% else %}'

    {# SEARCH RESULT FAILURE #}

    <div class="alert alert-danger page-title-center">
        <h3 style="padding-top:1em;">Could Not Find Results For: {{ page.filter_term }}</span></h3>
    </div>
   {% endif %}

</section>
{% endif %}
```

*Models.py*

```
@route(r"^search/$")
    def post_search(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search_query = request.GET.get("q", None) 
        self.posts = self.get_posts()
        if search_query:
            self.filter_term = search_query
            self.filter_type = 'search'
            self.posts = self.posts.search(search_query)
        return self.render(request)
```

Comment: The model code you've posted does not set a variable called `results`, so either that's your problem, or there's some code that gets called in between that you need to show us. Even so, I don't believe there's ever any situation where both branches of an {% if %} / {% else %} tag would be taken - is that really the exact template code that produces the above screenshot?

Comment: Instead of 'results', I've tried 'search_query', 'filter_term', and 'filter_type', to whit, I have no idea what to place in this if/else statement.

And no, the screenshot above is without the {% if results %} / {% else %} statement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. Instead of `{% if results %}`, simply change it to `{% if posts %}`

The `posts` comes from `self.posts`, which comes from `self.posts = self.posts.search(search_query)`

*ANSWER*:

```
{% if page.filter_term %}
<section>

   {% if posts %}
    {# SEARCH RESULT SUCCESSFUL #}

    <div class="alert alert-success page-title-center">
        <h3 style="padding-top:1em;">Search Results For: <span>{{ page.filter_term }}</span></h3>
    </div>

   {% else %}

    {# SEARCH RESULT FAILURE #}

    <div class="alert alert-danger page-title-center">
        <h3 style="padding-top:1em;">Could Not Find Results For: {{ page.filter_term }}</span></h3>
    </div>
   {% endif %}

</section>
{% endif %}
```